# Error by foreign key use in MySQL Workbench,error code 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

1.Hello I have a problem with my SQL code.I become Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax.

> 2.Error:13:05:36   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ID_Mannschaft    FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Mannschaft`) REFERENCES `Mannschaft`(`ID_Mannschaft`)   ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ID_Mannschaft    FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Mannschaft`) REFERENCES `Man' at line 1    0.032 sec

```
    ALTER TABLE `Trainier`
    ADD `ID_Mannschaft` INT NOT NULL,
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ID_Mannschaft 
    FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Mannschaft`) REFERENCES `Mannschaft`(`ID_Mannschaft`)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: no syntax is ok, do you have exact error message?

Comment: Can you share the exact error message you're getting please? Offhand the syntax looks OK

Comment: Post structure of Mannschaft, for a foreign key it is necessary that there must be a primary/unique key in the parent table and data type of both fields must be same

Comment: i think you have more code and the erro is before your posted code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the structure given below, no error found, pls check data type and constraint.

```
Create Table Mannschaft (ID_Mannschaft Int, Constraint Primary Key (ID_Mannschaft));
Create Table Trainier (ID VarChar(40));


ALTER TABLE `Trainier`
    ADD `ID_Mannschaft` INT NOT NULL,
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ID_Mannschaft 
    FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Mannschaft`) REFERENCES `Mannschaft`(`ID_Mannschaft`)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```